# html:title in pure XML document

Tags: html, xml

I decided to use pure XML+CSS instead of (X)HTML for my webpage.
I use  and  with no problems.
However I can't specify webpage's title.

Document looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css"?>
<html:html xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html:head>
<html:title>FooBar</html:title>
</html:head>
<site>

<header>foo</header>

<article>
<title>foo</title>
<p>foo bar <html:a href="#">foobar</html:a></p>
</article>

</site>
</html:html>
```

But it doesn't work.

Update: it works on Chrome and Internet Explorer. Doesn't work on Firefox.

Comment: You are using XHTML - why are you doing it this way?

Comment: Why would you use pure XML instead of XHTML, or, even better, HTML?

Comment: This way, I can use custom tags such as <header> <content> <footer> <article> and so on. And XHTML is only syntactic sugar over HTML.

Comment: HTML5 adds a lot of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Looks like a Firefox bug to me. I can't think of a reason why this shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I used XSLT to do this. Works like a charm on every browser.

Comment: **How** did you achieve your aims using xslt? The purpose of a posted question is to help others with the same problem, as well as yourself. If you could post your solution it would be appreciated.

Comment: In fact "Looks like a Firefox bug to me" must be right. I tested few web browsers and every one except FF used html:title as page's title.

I used XSLT because XML+CSS occured to be insufficient to my needs. Its completely different method.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you leave xhtml as it is and use another namespace with an alias for your custom tags?

**Edit**

I mean something like:-

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:a="urn:mycrop.com:mystuff">
<head>
<title>FooBar</title>
</head>
<a:site>

<a:header>foo</a:header>

<a:article>
<a:title>foo</a:title>
<p>foo bar <a href="#">foobar</a></p>
</a:article>

</a:site>
</html>
```

Of course this will fail if the browser strictly expects XHTML but that was true of your originally anyway.

From your comments elsewhere in this question it looks like you've gone for XSLT as a stylesheet anyway.  That being the case you needn't bother with including any of the HTML stuff anyway, just have the source XML contain the data you want to display.

Comment: Could you explain it a bit? Currently it looks like this:

<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css"?>
<html:html xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html:head>
<html:title>FooBar</html:title>
</html:head>
<site>

<header>foo</header>

<article>
<title>foo</title>
<p>foo bar <html:a href="#">foobar</html:a></p>
</article>

</site>
</html:html>

Comment: Please don't post code in comments it doesn't format usefully.   If you have more details to add simply edit your question.

Comment: @Developer AnthonyWJones probably meant something along the lines of using regular XHTML extended by `<myNameSpace:article>` etc. I.e. going "the other way round."

Comment: have a look at how e.g. mathml is embedded in xhtml http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#well-formed